# How to disable a button after click for only 3 seconds in a WinUI 3 Application?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have a button that I want to disable for 3 seconds so that it's not abused. I wanted to add a `Timer(3000);` inside the `Click` event however the example code I found is using outdated method and is not working. I tried another code (which can be found below) however this throws `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'` error.

```
private void CodeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CodeButton.IsEnabled = false;
    var timer = new Timer(3000);
    timer.Elapsed += (timer_s, timer_e) =>
    {
            CodeButton.IsEnabled = true;
            timer.Dispose();

    };
    timer.Start();
    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.hoppie.nl/acars/system/register.html"));
}
```

Comment: .NET has 3 different Timer types with different threading characteristics.  As such you need to use the right one.  e.g. in WinForms it is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  Going by your code it looks like you are using `System.Timers.Timer` which is _"is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment."_, hence your error - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: But I'm not working on a WPF application, it'sa WinUI 3 application.

Comment: _"But I'm not working on a WPF application"_ - so?  No GUI framework is multithreaded.  _"Multithreaded toolkits, a failed dream"_, Oracle.  The error you are getting is a clear indication of my point.  As for WinUI, that's just a re-packaged and re-purposed WinRT/UWP framework.

Comment: Sorry I'm learning WinUI on the go and with so many frameworks, packages etc. things get confusing. Apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the main thread (the thread that instantiated UI components) to update UI. You get that error because the timer will work with another thread, not the main thread.

You can do it this way:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // You can update the UI because
        // the Click event will use the main thread.
        this.Button.IsEnabled = false;

        List<Task> tasks = new();
        // The main thread will be released here until
        // LaunchUriAsync returns.
        tasks.Add(Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.hoppie.nl/acars/system/register.html")));
        tasks.Add(Task.Delay(3000));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        // The main thread will be back here.
    }
    finally
    {
        // This will enable the button even if you face exceptions.
        this.Button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! With your code I'm getting `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<bool>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'` error. I tried to explicitly cast `LauncherUriAsync()` but that did not work as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cptalpdeniz just use the `AsTask` extension method